# axios error response returns undefined if request is successful

Tags: javascript, axios

Hello i am using axios with React & Redux like this

```
export const addCustomer = ({destructured data}) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/customer-base/add-customer', {
        //data
    })
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_CUSTOMER,
            payload: {
              newCustomer: data.newCustomer
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if(err.response.data.message){
            console.log(err.response.data.message)
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_CUSTOMER_ERROR,
                payload: {
                   error: err.response.data.message
                }
            })
        }


   })
}
```

and after successful  request (returning 200 status code) it gives me this error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

the most interesting thing is that it only gives me this error after sending 200 status code. if there is error message it works fine. so what is problem? i added CORS header but it did not work and when i add `if(err.response){ }` and inside this condition i handle my error it also works fine. so i want to know the problem

Comment: is the two `then`s the issue? According to the documentation, it is only one

Comment: looks like it's failing here: `res.data` which indicates that the `res` is undefined, which would mean that you return a 200 success code with an empty body?

Comment: nope, two then is not a problem, i just return data from res.data to avoid writing res.data.something everytime, i use this technique in every axios request and it works fine

Comment: i do not meant that "data" parameter in `then` is undefined, the undefined one is in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add "config" to your post request:

```
dispatch({ type: ADD_CUSTOMER_REQUEST });
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};
const { data } = await axios.post("/api/customer-base/add-customer", ThatdestructuredData*, config);
```